# How can I transform the output of strsplit into a dataframe mantaining an id by list?

Tags: r, list, web-scraping, strsplit

I've **scraped** 26 html's into a data frame that I have to split by a pattern. data example:

```
vers<-c("El Señor te bendiga y te guarde; el Señor te mire con agrado y te extienda su amor; el Señor te muestre su favor y te conceda la paz",
        "Eviten toda conversación obscena. Por el contrario, que sus palabras contribuyan a la necesaria edificación y sean de bendición para quienes escuchan",
        "No seas sabio en tu propia opinión; más bien, teme al Señor y huye del mal. Esto infundirá salud a tu cuerpo y fortalecerá tu ser.",
        "Den gracias a Dios en toda situación, porque esta es su voluntad para ustedes en Cristo Jesús",
        "¡Cuán bueno y cuán agradable es que los hermanos convivan en armonía! ",
        "Tú, Señor, eres mi porción y mi copa; eres tú quien ha afirmado mi suerte.",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla",
        "bla bla señor bla bla")



data<-c("1 enero 2020",
        "2 enero 2020",
        "3 enero 2020",
        "4 enero 2020",
        "5 enero 2020",
        "6 enero 2020",
        "7 enero 2020",
        "8 enero 2020",
        "9 enero 2020",
        "10 enero 2020",
        "11 enero 2020",
        "12 enero 2020",
        "13 enero 2020",
        "14 enero 2020",
        "15 enero 2020",
        "16 enero 2020",
        "17 enero 2020",
        "18 enero 2020",
        "19 enero 2020",
        "20 enero 2020",
        "21 enero 2020",
        "22 enero 2020",
        "23 enero 2020",
        "24 enero 2020",
        "25 enero 2020",
        "26 enero 2020")


vers_123 <- data.frame(data,vers, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

This is the output I get (a list with 26 lists of concatenated vectors):

[image]

Now I want to transform it into a data.frame mantaining this structure. Or at least I would like to keep an ID of the list (26 ID, for each splitted text inside each list)

I've tried to use unlist, but this way I get all the splitted documents in one list. which makes it impossible to know which document(row) they belong to.

I've tried the code below too, but this code doesn't identify correctly the list from the second row onwards (I suppose because each of the 26 lists don't have the same length)

```
     vers123_splitted<-unlist(strsplit2 (vers_123$vers, split= "Señor|Dios",type = "before"))
cols <- c("z1", "z2","z3","z4")
nC <- length(cols)
ind <- seq(from=1, by=nC, length=nrow(vers_123))
for(i in 1:nC) {
  vers123_splitted[, cols[i]] <- vers[ind + i - 1]
}
```

I would like to have something like this:

[image]